# What is the role of the Gentiles in the world?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws

What is the role of the Gentiles in the world? The Jews say theirs is to be a nation of priesthood and a light to the nations. Okay and the gentiles? What do they have to play in this world? For example we only have the seven laws of Noah, all are negative laws, don't do this, don't do that and their ramifications, isn't there a positive commandment or that makes us special can we say to perform?

Even the commandment to multiply is said to be closed for the Gentiles, what is left? Understand, I'm not willing to accept more obligations, as a Gentile I'm happy to have few obligations to fulfill before God, I just want to know if there is an explanation for this apparent lack of ultimate goal of the Gentiles.

Could this be because they are nations and it is not possible to generalize their functions in the world like the Jew is because he is a unique nation? I've heard some explanation within Judaism that our function as Gentiles is to elevate the earthly world and that would be achieved by participating in the world, proving everything that can be proven, not being ascetic about worldly things, I'm not sure what they meant by So maybe you can enlighten me on this issue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GInNEItFT9g&ab_channel=BneiNoachAcademy

Comment: Their role is to elevate the world in a logical fashion. All of the mitzvot for gentiles are logical and designed to maintain a healthy society, which is what God wants, and elevates the world. The Jews took on the responsibility of engaging in a more intimate relationship with God, keeping more mitzvot, including the non-sensical ones because they are personal to God. One day the whole world with thirst for knowledge of Hashem and I pray that everyone, gentile and Jew, will seek an intimate relationship with God (something mankind abandoned way back before Abraham)!

Comment: I understood the difference. From what I could research, can we classify Jews as a people who need to be holy and Gentiles can be more liberal in the eyes of God? Are we more permissive with the things of the world than the Jews?

Comment: I think you should try to convert that to its own question, I'm not 100% sure what you mean, such as what do you mean by holy, or permissive, in context, and what prompted the question. Either way, non-Jews have less mitzvot, but the level of obligation they have with them isn't any different to that of Jews, and there are mitzvot for non-Jews about holiness, such as with adultery, and idol worship. An interesting question, either way.

Comment: As a personal feeling - I would imagine God is hoping that a gentile will look with envy at the Jewish closeness with Hashem, saying "how come Hashem doesn't expect more of _me_, and give me more mitzvot" and strive to show God that he can do more than He expects of him. The Torah does say a lot of negative things about people who pursue permissibility (in the same way a wife might be hurt when her husband has an attitude of trying to get out of as many obligations as he can towards her)

Comment: I understood. I think we as Gentiles can barely deal with the only seven laws of Noah and some like me already feel entitled to demand more without being exact in the seven laws, I think that's it, thanks for the advice and point of view, I hadn't seen it from that angle

Comment: Please check out this hot off the press video, the best you'll get for all your questions! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxetw26uWII